# how to save an array of comma-separated strings into Excel file format

Tags: javascript, node.js

In mu node app, I have an array of comma-separated string, which looks like this:

```
column1, column2, column3
value1,value2, value3
value4, value5, value6
```

What module or method could I use to save this array as an Excel (.xlsx) spreadsheet document?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want .xlsx instead of simply .csv?

Comment: As far as I can tell an XLSX file is a zipped collection of XML files. You would have to zip it in JS and transform your data into XML. That's a lot of code, while a CSV would be saving a multi-line string straight away.

Comment: Yes - the reason is that I'm using XLSX module to parse the resulting file, and to convert it to json, for further submission to mongodb

Comment: *"I'm using XLSX module to parse the resulting file"* Why not directly convert the string to an object (or JSON)? Seems much easier.

Comment: My app deals with Excel files, which come from different people, but alsways in .xlsx format.  Some of these files have unwanted characters in the top (headers) row, so I have to convert each file into a .csv first, in order to be able to access the top row, and do a global replacement of the unwanted characters. then, I will need to convert the cleaned-up csv back to .xls, so the XLSX module can read it, and convert to array of json objects, where object keys no longer have those unwanted characters

Comment: I don't think such a thing exists. You are better off writing a wrapper in Node.js that calls a C# program to spit out CSV files.